# Taking an input from a file in java

Tags: java

My file

```
123
```

Code:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
int[] a = br.readline(); // will give me a number 123 not an array
```

I have also used **StringTokenzier** which is also giving me a number not an array.

Expected Output:

```
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
```

Please help me

Comment: *"Please help me"* ... do what?

Comment: What you want to achieve please explain clearly

Comment: I think he wants to convert `123` into `{1,2,3}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use `String#toCharArray` which will give you each individual character...

```
String text = br.readLine();
char[] characters= text.toCharArray();
```

You would then need to convert each character to an `int`, something like...

```
int numbers[] = new int[characters.length];
for (int index = 0; index < characters.length; index++) {
    numbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(characters[index]));
}
```

Comment: @TheLostMind *"each character to a ..."* - and yes, I added the conversion as well...

Comment: Add a regex to validate the string is number `\\d*`

Comment: @Barun That's an option, or you could just deal with the `NumberFormatException` thrown by `Integer.parseInt` alert you to problems with the value, horse for course...

Comment: @MadProgrammer is there any direct method to convert my input(i.e 123) to an integer array

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
char[] cArr = br.readLine().toCharArray();
int[] iArr = new int[cArr.length];
int i = 0;
for(char c : cArr) {
  iArr[i++] = Character.getNumericValue(c);
}
```

**Note:** Invalid data can cause un-expected output as described in [docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char))

Comment: That's interesting, but wait fail if the input is invalid (ie `a`, which returns `10`), if the value can not be converted to a numeric value, it will return -1 or -2...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I agree with you, hence I had mentioned in the post, but I guess same applies to your solution. An invalid data like `a` can give a nice `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Yeah, but at least you know about, this approach just gives you back an erroneous results ...